# Checking from a preemptive evaluation whether a main evaluation is ongoing

Tags: dynamic

How can I programmatically check from a [preemptive evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#681967067) whether a main evaluation is currently ongoing?

I need a function `mainEvaluationOngoingQ[]` so that

```
Button["Evaluating?", Print@mainEvaluationOngoingQ[], Method -> "Preemptive"]
```

will print `True` only if a main evaluation is ongoing.

Answer (score 14):

If you control the launch of the main evaluation process, then a very simple way is to wrap your code in a dynamic environment (`Block`), which would set some flag:

```
mainEvaluationOngoingQ[] := TrueQ@mainEvaluationQ

Block[{mainEvaluationQ = True}, Do[i^2, {i, 1, 10^8}]]
```

You can automate this by creating an environment:

```
SetAttributes[withMainEvaluation, HoldAll];
withMainEvaluation[code_] :=
    Block[{mainEvaluationQ = True}, code]
```

You can further automate this with `$Pre`, if needed: `$Pre = withMainEvaluation`.

Comment: +1 Very nice. I hope his main evaluations aren't triggered by buttons with `Method->"Queued"`. Any way to cover those cases too?

Comment: @Rojo If buttons are generated in the same session, then I'd write a preprocessor that would dynamically generate code where the body of the button is wrapped in `withMainEvaluation`. If not, one can probably write code which would pre-process a notebook and change that at the box level. Other than that, I don't know how to do this - this may need some lower-level stuff.

Comment: I'm *very* late with this, but isn't that question superfluous: With `Method->"Queued"`, the evaluation is queued to be evaluated using the main link, so there by definition isn't a (-nother) main evaluation running, and `mainEvaluationOngoing` always returns `False`, which is correct when interpreted as "is another main evaluation ongoing". Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AlbertRetey Yes, but IIRC, the question was about how to determine whether or not the main evaluation is ongoing, from the preemptive evaluation, not from the queued one.

Answer (score 3):

The following works with Mathematica 8.0.0.0:

```
Button["Evaluating?",Print@(Drop[Stack[],-7]!={}),Method->"Preemptive"]
```

However the `-7` here is an empirical factor which removes all those entries generated from executing the button code itself; it changes depending on the exact form of the code the `Stack[]` is embedded in, and might even depend on the Mathematica version (I don't think the inner mechanics of `Button` is documented, let alone guaranteed never to change).